# Can I online-play a game purchased on one account when logged into another account set to a different locale?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

On my PS4, I have one PSN account with my location set as India, and another account with location entered as United States. I have a PS Plus membership on my 1st account but not the 2nd account.

When I log into my PS4 using the 2nd (US) account I can see all my downloaded games and able to play them online (even though no PS Plus membership is used). My question is: if I purchase the game through PS store from 2nd account will I be able to play online if I logged in using either account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes

For games, 'Main' or 'Secondary' accounts can buy/download it and the game will be available for all accounts on the same PS4 system.
With any account you download the game, **you'll be able to play it on every account of that same console** (no matter where it says it's located).

What you **can't** do is buy the Plus subscription on a secondary account, because it will only work on that account and on none other even on that system.